# cakephp 3.0 using tableprefix?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Moving on from a cakephp 2 application, I am stuck on trying to use $tablePrefix in my models.
Is this still available in Cake 3? Or how can I use something else (please explain).

Answer (score 3):

Table prefixes are gone for now. There is an open PR, however it's not clear at this point when, and if at all this is going to make it:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4505**

As mentioned by Lorenzo in the comments, an alternative might be using events to initialize models with a prefixed table name:

> For people still wanting support for prefixes in their tables, there is a way to support it using events. This will probably work for all table operations. Add it to your bootstrap.php file:
>
> ```
> EventManager::instance()->on('Model.initialize', function ($event, $instance) {
>     $instance->table('prefix_' . $instance->table());
> });
> ```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4505#issuecomment-76154855**

Comment: Thank you! No wonder I could not find it.
Shame I can not use cake when using this workaround. It is a shame that the 'makers' of cakephp live in a different world from the users...........

Comment: Why you can't use cakephp when using that workaround?

Comment: @Snelweg It's **not** a workaround it's the proper place to do it. I was wondering myself why its missing in the connection settings but after some discussion with Lorenzo I realized that this in fact should be done on the tabel level. The ORM can support other data sources that *don't* use or know about tables at all, for example CSV, REST or Graph databases. The prefix can be still made configurable by simply using the Configure class to read the prefix from the config.

Comment: @JoséLorenzo I meant bake not cake. Sorry

Comment: @ndm this does not work for me .. i m using cakephp 3.x and i put this code **EventManager::instance()->on('Model.initialize', function ($event, $instance) {
    $instance->table('5p_' . $instance->table());
}); ** in **bootstrap.php** and i am having this error saying *Fatal error: Call to a member function table() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\5p_group\config\bootstrap.php*

Comment: @ndm also i have put this code in bootstrap.php **use Cake\Event\EventManager;**

Answer (score 3):

To get prefix per table like you did in `2.x` just do this in your Table class:

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->table('my_prefix_' . $this->table());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm migrating some cake2.x code to cake3. A slight alteration to ndm's code has worked for me so far in bootstrap.php, along these lines:

```
Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on('Model.initialize', function ($event) {
    $instance = $event->subject;
    if ($instance->defaultConnectionName() == 'default') {           
        $instance->table('prefix_' . $instance->table());
    }
});
```