# CakePHP 3 table prefix__

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is there solution, how to set global prefix for database tables in cakephp3? I found the prefix is not implemented yet.

Is there another solution? Code something to cake libraries on the right place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp 3.0 using tableprefix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792720/cakephp-3-0-using-tableprefix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not implementet in Cakephp-3.x so far. But there are some workarounds.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4118