# Cakephp 3 table-prefix in cake bake

Tags: cakephp, cake-bake

How to set global prefix for database tables in cakephp3? I need to insert a prefix for the table.

Can the table prefix be used in Cake Bake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cakephp 3.0 using tableprefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792720/cakephp-3-0-using-tableprefix)

Comment: ```bin/cake bake model Users --tablePrefix forum```  https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1.x/en/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/cake bake model UserRecords -c records --table tbl_records_user
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).