# CAKEPHP 4.X Model prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

With few blogs inspiration, we have started upgrading our existing project from Cakephp-2X version to Cakephp-4X. We started it from scratch. Now we have been stuck with few things -

1. How to give prefix to a particular table in the model and also on fly in the controller?
2. In Cakephp-4X, we can list out virtual fields in Entity it seems, But  how to give virtual fields on fly in the controller like in Cake2X?
3. In Cake2X, we can also give conditions based on the virtual fields for model find method. But, how is it possible in Cake4.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The first step to upgrading is to stop thinking about the cakephp 2 and how you developed it. The rest is getting easier.

Comment: Ok thanks @Salines, How to give prefix to a particular table in the model and also on fly in the controller? This question is not about the version, its a kind of requirement. If you know this, please respond.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792720/cakephp-3-0-using-tableprefix

Comment: Got it fixed. Thanks @Salines. Here is the code on fly i.e controller.
TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get("Users")->setTable('changeTableName');